# Httpclient request on internal server returns timeout c#

Tags: c#, windows-services, .net-5, dotnet-httpclient, windows-server-2016

I created a windows service (c# .net5) that connects with slack websocket. The connection start by going to slackAPI first to request the websocket address and then make the connection with the slack server. I wrote a code to get that websocket address and it works fine on my local machine. However, when I launch my service app to our internal windows server 2016, that request get cancelled by timeout.

```
The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 60 seconds elapsing.
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 60 seconds elapsing.
 ---> System.TimeoutException: The operation was canceled.
 ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(Func`3 callback, DnsEndPoint endPoint, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at GetWebSocketUrl() in C:\Users\filename.cs:line 130
```

I tried to increase the timeout to 5 min but still no success.
After some research I found this issue and tried to add headers on my code (see below) but still nothing. ([Why can the C# HttpClient not call this URL (always times out)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790438/why-can-the-c-sharp-httpclient-not-call-this-url-always-times-out?newreg=695f8705ede74aa6879ea28945df75d4))

Any leads that could help me find a solution would be appreciated.

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    HttpContent content = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                    httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko; Google Page Speed Insights) Chrome/27.0.1453 Safari/537.36");
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", SLACK_TOKEN);
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(SLACK_URI, content);
                    string bodyResponseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    dynamic jsonBody = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(bodyResponseString);

                    if (jsonBody["ok"] == "True")
                    {
                        return jsonBody["url"];
                    }
                }
```

Comment: It's possible the issue is network connectivity (i.e. has nothing to do with your code.) Have you tried connecting via some other tool, e.g. `telnet` on port 443, or PostMan, or even a regular browser?

Comment: Network connectivity, and / or any other environmental factor

Comment: I made sure that the url was working using the chrome browser which returned me a unauthorize response (expected) @JohnWu

Comment: @TheGeneral, do you have any in mind that i could try on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it was a proxy issue. Just needed to add the proxy on the httpClient and it worked fine.

```
        IWebProxy _proxyConfig = new WebProxy
        {
            Address = new Uri($"{proxyIp}:{proxyPort}"),
            BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
            UseDefaultCredentials = true,
        };
        HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Proxy = _proxyConfig,
        };
        using (HttpClient _client = new HttpClient(handler: httpClientHandler)) {...}
```